# how to fix issue when ngrx entity returned undefined for id

Tags: ngrx-entity

why am getting this below error and how to fix this .

The entity passed to the selectId implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own selectId implementation. The entity that was passed:

Answer (score 13):

Probably you are passing an entity which has no id property. So you need to override the `selectId` method in the `EntityAdapter` creation.

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<YourInterface> =
  createEntityAdapter<YourInterface>({
    selectId: nameofclass => nameofclass.yourID
  });
```

Comment: Where does this go? I've tried adding it, but it is not hitting it.

Comment: This goes at the initialization of the adapter for that specific entity @Godrules500

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by specifying metadata for several entities at the same time in an EntityMetadataMap:

```
// entity-store.module.ts

...

export function selectEventId(event: Event): number {
  return event.eventId;
}

export const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  User: {},
  Event: {
    selectId: selectEventId
  }
};

...
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is typically linked to missing - *Entity primary key*:

Every entity type must have a primary key whose value is an integer or a string.
The NgRx Data library assumes that the entity has an "id" property, whose value is the primary key.

Not every entity will have a primary key property named "id".
For some entities, the primary key could have any name or could be a combined value of two or more properties. In these cases, you always specify the primary key for that entity using the function:

***[selectId](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#selectid)***

This function returns the primary key value of the specified field/property of that entity.

For example:

Entity Villain does not have a primary key named "id", but it is named "key".
For this entity, the *selectId* function is this:

```
selectId: (villain: Villain) => villain.key;
```

And the full declaration of the entity metadata could be something like:

File: ../entity-store.module.ts

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {

    ...

    Villain: {
                       // We MUST specify a primary key / id field for each entity
                       // (if it does not have its own prop/field named: 'id') !!!
        selectId: (villain: Villain) => villain.key, // <--- 

                       // optional setting - filter
        filterFn: filterForVillains,
                       // optional setting - sort order
        sortComparer: sortVillains
    },

    Hero { ... },

    ....

}
```